# Apps and Interface looks different

Tags: applications

Why is Android on mobiles made by different companies different, and why do apps like Facebook also differ likewise?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system on your phone isn't put there by Google: it's put there by the manufacturer of the phone (the *OEM*). Google gives OEMs the source code to Android, and the OEM has to integrate its drivers into the phone. The OEM can also make any changes to Android, as long as it still passes the compatibility tests (so that apps will run on it).

The OEMs like to use this facility to make changes, first to add their own branding, and second to add features they regard as "value add". OEMs want to differentiate their phones from their competitors this way. They don't want to become like PC manufacturers, who don't have as much ability to customize, because PC manufacturing has much lower margins.

Comment: Beat my wasted draft to it.

Comment: But why apps like Facebook are slightly different from my lg mobile in other mobiles made by lennovo and samsung ?

Comment: @Arunkumar I don't quite see what you mean. Could you [edit] your question to explain what differences you're talking about? Add screenshots if it helps.

Comment: I mean the  user interface of Facebook is not similar in my lg mobile and in my friends lennovo mobile. Iennovo has a different layout for Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Android is open-source. Anyone can modify it at their own wish. OEMs, original equipment manufacturers, specificallt like differentiating their products from others' by customizing Android.

There are several popular modified Android UI variants like LineageOS (previously CyanogenMod), MIUI and whatever UI it's called. Most modifications are intended to either provide more functionality, or make Android look better. A lot of modifications do mot intefere with the lower part of Android - they only change what it looks like, but not how it works. This can be easily done even by installing another launcher (so you have a different desktop look and functionality).

As of now, the vanilla Android can only be found on Google phones like Pixel's and Nexus'. But that's not a big issue unless you're a Google maniac. OEM-modded Android are required to pass a series of tests to ensure it's compatible with Google's vanilla Android so that apps and games and run.